# iOS: Path to Twitter URL using JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to pull in the first url of a tweet using `-objectForKey:`, and I was wondering how I can pull in the expanded url in 1 go.

Here's the json:

```
"entities":{
      "hashtags":[

      ],
      "symbols":[

      ],
      "urls":[
         {
            "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/example",
            "expanded_url":"http:\/\/example.com\/hi",
            "display_url":"example.com\/hi",
            "indices":[
               46,
               68
            ]
         }
      ],
      "user_mentions":[

      ]
   },
```

This is what I tried: `NSLog(@"URL FOUND: %@", [JSON objectForKey:@"entities/urls/expanded_url"]);` 
but I got (`null`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will be help for you

```
NSArray *urls = [[JSON objectForKey:@"entities"] objectForKey:@"urls"];
NSString *url = [[urls objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"url"];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"urls":[
     {
        "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/example",
        "expanded_url":"http:\/\/example.com\/hi",
        "display_url":"example.com\/hi",
        "indices":[
           46,
           68
        ]
     }
  ],
```

Here, value of `urls` is an array, so you should use path like `entities/urls[0]/expanded_url`

**Update:**

I don't know which JSON decode library you use.

Take famous `JSONKit`(https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) as an example:

```
NSString *str = @"{\"entities\":{\"urls\":[{\"url\":\"http://t.co/example\"}]}}";
NSDictionary *dict = [str objectFromJSONString];
NSLog(@"URL: %@",dict[@"entities"][@"urls"][0][@"url"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @LeeWong unfortunately it still didn't work. I still get (null).

Comment: I also tried: entities/urls/[0]/expanded_url but it also returns null.